# Mapping few columns in sap.ui.table.Table using ODataModel?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am binding all the columns of a table except one which is drop down. The table is tied to a model(ODataModel) and the contents of the drop downs in the last columns are all the coming from different model because user shall be selecting one item from the drop down later which is submitted on the click of a button 'Save' I have provided in the bottom.

I am making use of Paginator as Navigation mode. The problem is dropdown shows the contents of first page when user switches between the pages which is eventual as it is not tied to any of the fields in the model of the table. I want to show the respective changes to be reflected in the column of drop down though user switches between the pages.

Any suggestion over this? I know there is something called RowRepeater using which complex controls can be repeated but still what would be the way if I want to make use of sap.ui.table.Table?

Please find my code below:

```
createAssignResourcesTable: function(){ 
    var model = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSECENTRAL_SRV", true);
    var substituteRMCombo = sap.ui.getCore().byId("substituteRM");
    var selectedRM = substituteRMCombo.getSelectedKey();
    var jsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    var resourceData = null;
    var readSuccess = function(responseData){
        resourceData = responseData;
        jsonModel.setData(resourceData);
    };
    var readError = function(){
        //console.log('some error occurred while reading data');
        sap.ui.commons.MessageBox.show("Some Error occurred while reading data",
                sap.ui.commons.MessageBox.Icon.ERROR,"Error!",[sap.ui.commons.MessageBox.Action.OK],
                function(){
                    //console.log('End Date should be grater than Start aDte!!!');
                    return;
            });
    };
     model.read("/RMResourceSet",null, null, true,readSuccess,readError);
    var template = new sap.ui.core.ListItem();
    //console.log(template);
    template.bindProperty("text","ChildbpName");
    template.bindProperty("key","Childbp");
    //console.log(template);
    var that = this;
    var table = new sap.ui.table.Table("assignResourcesTable",{
                   visibleRowCount: 6,
                   navigationMode: sap.ui.table.NavigationMode.Paginator,

                  columns:[
                           new sap.ui.table.Column("",{
                                label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text:"Work Item"}),
                                template: new sap.ui.commons.Label().bindProperty("text", "DemoId"),
                                sortProperty: "DemoId",
                                filterProperty: "DemoId",
                                width: "auto"
                           }), new sap.ui.table.Column("",{
                                label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text:"Requierd Date"}),
                                template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "ReqDate"),
                                sortProperty: "ReqDate",
                                filterProperty: "ReqDate",
                                width: "auto"
                           }),
                           new sap.ui.table.Column({
                               label: new sap.ui.commons.Label("",{
                                   text: "Estimated Hours"
                               }),
                               template: new sap.ui.commons.TextField("",{
                                   change:[{"name" : "DurEst"},that.onChangeAssignResourcesTable,that],
                                   value: "00015"
                               }).bindProperty("value","DurEst")
                           }),
                           new sap.ui.table.Column({
                               label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text:"Demo Engineer"}),
                               template: new sap.ui.commons.ComboBox("",{
                                   change:[{"name" : "Childbp"},that.onChangeAssignResourcesTable,that]
                               }).setModel(jsonModel).bindItems("/results",template),
                               width: "auto"
                           })

                  ]
              });
    table.setBusyIndicatorDelay(1);
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSECENTRAL_SRV",true);
    oModel.attachRequestSent(function (oEvent) {
        //console.log('request sent');
         table.setBusy(true);
    });
    oModel.attachRequestCompleted(function () {
            //console.log('request completed');
            table.setBusy(false);
    });
    oModel.attachRequestFailed(function () {
              table.setBusy(false);
    });
    table.setModel(oModel);
    var FilterOperator = sap.ui.model.FilterOperator;
    var filter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("RmUser", FilterOperator.EQ, selectedRM);
    table.bindRows("/RMNONSTAFFEDDBRSet",null,null,[filter]);
    //table.bindRows("/RMNONSTAFFEDDBRSet",true);
    return table;
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: seeing some sample data contained in jsonModel might help.

Answer (score 1):

Your ComboBox statically binds against jsonModel>results. Given the above code I would assume your ComboBox turns out to always contain the very same items.

I understood from your question that these items should be dynamic for each row or at least each page. Since the rows of a table can only be bound to one collection you have the following possibilities to tweak this:

1. Create a new `JSONModel` joining the data from your `ODataModel` with the data used for the `ComboBox` creation and bind your table against this new model.
2. Option 1 certainly has some weaknesses so here's another one: Bind your `ComboBox` column against any property of the `ODataModel` and use a [formatter function](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/07e4b920f5734fd78fdaa236f26236d8.html) to dynamically create the `ComboBox` items and return them from the formatter.